# Preventing vim to auto-expand folds

Tags: vim, folding

I'm using **foldmethod=marker** and **#{{{** **#}}}** markers in Python code.

After typing **#{{{** vim automatically expands all folds below the cursor.

Is it possible to turn this off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing block from the "foldopen" option.

```
:set foldopen-=block
```

Or maybe the foldclose=all option...

```
:set foldclose=all
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a match for the `# {{{` like `# {{{1` and then a `# }}}1`

Comment: Folds get expanded as soon as I press { for the third time, so I can't do this.